# How to Run C# as background in Winjs ,Windows store App

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, winjs

I have an Windows store app that's on HTML5 I listen somewhere that we will also able to apply C# as in other project and can easily pass function and variable to each other ?
So it is Possible to Add C# in HTML5 App ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the link to get How it will be done :

Windows Runtime Components ,

[Creating a simple component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)